# Buttons are not shown in real device but shown in emulator in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator

I have a `linearlayout` which has 2 buttons `cancel & download` which are use to cancel or download of image respectively. When I run the app on emulator [Emulator is Nexus-5] all works fine , these 2 buttons are shown, but when I test my app on real device [My device is samsung-core].

Image is loaded from internet and then this liearLayout is shown, initially it is hidden.

This is the `screenshot` from my device
[image: Device Screenshot]

## And this is my emulator `screenshot`

[image: Emulator Screenshot]

### This is layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_pic_url"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Enter pic url here" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bt_pic_search"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Send" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_pic"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
         />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear_layout_download_cancel_button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="32dp"
    android:paddingRight="32dp">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bt_cancel_download"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Cancel" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bt_pic_download"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Download" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I am guessing this is happening because of Screen Height. But why this 2 buttons get hidden.What is making this weird thing happen in my layout file.

Thanks - Suraj

Comment: your 2 buttons are hidden because your layout is longer than the screen size

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightsum="10"

>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp"
android:weight="1"
>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_pic_url"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Enter pic url here" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bt_pic_search"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Send" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
android:weight="8"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_pic"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
         />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear_layout_download_cancel_button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="32dp"
    android:paddingRight="32dp">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bt_cancel_download"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Cancel" />

<Button
        android:id="@+id/bt_pic_download"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Download" />
</LinearLayout>

enter code here

Your imageview is match parent, so it cover the screen, use the above code. it will workl fine
```

Answer (score 0):

try **ScrollView**. The Buttons may below your ImageView(and set your image view attr "wrap_content") or your layout.

demo below according your code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="16dp">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_pic_url"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Enter pic url here" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/bt_pic_search"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Send" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_pic"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linear_layout_download_cancel_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="32dp"
            android:paddingRight="32dp">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/bt_cancel_download"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Cancel" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/bt_pic_download"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Download" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because there is no space to show the button in the device. do as below

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="16dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/linear_layout_download_cancel_button"
    >

        <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_pic_url"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Enter pic url here"/>

        <Button
                android:id="@+id/bt_pic_search"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Send"/>  


        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_pic"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
        />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linear_layout_download_cancel_button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="32dp"
            android:paddingRight="32dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    >

        <Button
                android:id="@+id/bt_cancel_download"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Cancel"/>

        <Button
                android:id="@+id/bt_pic_download"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Download"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```